# Bandwidth waster algorithm for PHP

Tags: php, bandwidth

I am trying to create a software in PHP that can run continuously and keep on wasting bandwidth.

Can anyone one sugggest any solutions.

Comment: Yes, I want to simulate network load.

Comment: I am thinking of Java, but I am newbie in Java.

Comment: Then why would you think Java?

Comment: Because it can run multiple threads at once, whereas php is only one thread and also it can timeout.

Comment: You could open a few thousand `Keep-Alive` connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a huge file and make it publically accessible then just make a page which loads the image and then calls itself.

(Note this is an infinite loop so you should probably put something in to be able to stop it such as a time constraint or a counter)

Something like this idea might do:

```
<?php
//waster.php
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: 0');
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/hugeimage.jpg');
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/waster.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to waste bandwidth you don't need a continuously running php script. It will waste processing not bandwidth. Just write a PHP script to Display a large Image file and write a utility or script (unix) in a local machine to continuously call that url and download the image and perhaps delete it.

Anyway seems like something evil is going to happen :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to [simulate network latency](http://helephant.com/2012/07/11/simulating-network-latency-with-fiddler/)  or [slow connection speeds](http://www.developertipoftheday.com/2010/12/simulate-slow-internet-connection-in.html).